# Random take profit and stop loss on pine script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

here is the description of the issue:
In my strategy: i open trade with a condition and i create an exit with a take profit target and at stop loss. Those two are constant ( in my case its always 4% of take profit percent /SL)

But often, when i look at the list of trades the profit isn't at all 4% or -4% sometimes its 4.3% or 5% or it can be 2%.Like you can see on the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oIN1.png)

I asked tradingview staff and they told me to set calc_on_order_fills=true and/or calc_on_every_tick=true to calculate information not on the historical close but on every tick.
I did it but i still have the same issue, take profit and stop loss are random.
and when i only take long nor short it still the same.(because maybe short position could have close a long idk)

Do you have an idea?
And of course i don't have any strategy.close() in my code the only way a trade end is by touching the stop loss or take profit. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We can't guess without code.  Provide compilable example with problem reproducing.

Comment: You likely need to init your stop/limit variables with var, but we need some code to work with !

Comment: I have something similar but posted more details and code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940494/pine-script-exit-with-take-profit-closes-positions-different-than-set-profit-per